# Crystal Reports section not supressing (CR for VS2008)

Tags: crystal-reports

So I have a report that has 2 details sections - a main details section (**Details a**) and a secondary details section (**Details b**). **Details a** should always be displayed and works fine.

However, **Details b** contains a few static text objects, a few line objects and one Formula Field which can be either "" (empty string) or have text in it.

If the Formula Field has text in it (i.e., != "") then I want the **Details b** section to be shown and if it is == "" then I want the entire **Details b** section to be suppressed.

I have added the following formula to the **Details b** *Section Expert* - `{@CageCardNumbersConditional} = ""` so that if the Formula Field is an empty string it SHOULD suppress the section but the section shows up whether the Formula Field has text in it or not. Also, I have tried checking the "Suppress Blank Section" checkbox and tried NOT checking the checkbox...both ways the section still shows up.

So I have tested the report with text in the Formula Field and without text in the Formula Field, with the "Suppress Blank Section" checkbox checked and with it unchecked, with the `{@CageCardNumbersConditional} = ""` formula and with the

```
 `If {@CageCardNumbersConditional} = ""Then 
      true 
  Else 
      false;`
```

formula, and I have even removed all of the text objects and line objects from the section just to make sure that it wasn't them keeping the section from being suppressed...but in EVERY test the section is NOT being suppressed.

Any suggestions with what I'm missing?

Thanks, George

Comment: Could you post the code for {@CageCardNumbersConditional}?

Comment: OK, I figured out what I did wrong. I had the suppress formula in the "Suppress Blank Section" formula area but once I added it to the "Suppress (No Drill-Down)" area it started working properly.

Comment: Thanks Ryan for your comments!!

Answer (score 0):

This is dependent on what, exactly, {@CageCardNumbersConditional} is doing, but try `isnull({@CageCardNumbersConditional})` instead of `{@CageCardNumbersConditional}=""`. It's possible {@CageCardNumbersConditional} is not doing what you think and is instead returning a null instead of the empty string, which are both distinct in CR.

Comment: FYI...here is what is in @CageCardNumbersConditional:

Comment: If {Request.ExtrnalCageCardSheetAttached} = false then {Request.CageCardNumbers} else ""